# JQuery Append form not posting in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to append table row which contains HTML form. The append form data not passing to controller. My Code is -

```
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>controller/function_name">
<table class="table table-bordered tbsize tb_wp" id="">
<thead>
  <tr >

    <th class="firstrow">Item No.</th>
    <th class="firstrow">Part No.</th>
    <th class="firstrow">Qty</th>
    <th class="firstrow">Price Quoted </th>
    <th class="firstrow"> Notes </th>
    <th class="firstrow">Internal Notes</th>  
    <th colspan="3" class="firstrow2">  
      <div class="pcrsec">
              <div class="row"><span class="pcrsecbor">Perior Customer RFQ</span></div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="pcrsec2">
                  <ul class="list-inline">
                      <li>Date</li>
                        <li>Cust No</li>
                        <li>Price</li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
    </th>

    <th colspan="3" class="firstrow3">          
            <div class="pcrsec">
              <div class="row"><span class="pcrsecbor">Perior Customer P/O</span></div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="pcrsec2">
                  <ul class="list-inline">
                      <li>Date</li>
                        <li>Cust No</li>
                        <li>Price</li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
   </th>
    <th colspan="3" class="firstrow4">

       <div class="pcrsec">
              <div class="row"><span class="pcrsecbor">Perior Vendor P/O</span></div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="pcrsec2">
                  <ul class="list-inline">
                      <li>Date</li>
                        <li>Cust No</li>
                        <li>Price</li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>       
   </th>
  <th class="firstrow">MU%</th>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="what_i_do">
  <tr>

    <td><input type="text" name="item_no[]"></td>
    <td colspan="3">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="smlbox" name="part_no[]" onblur="checkavailpart(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="smlbox" name="qty[]"></td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="smlbox price_quotd_cls" name="price_quotd[]">
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><input type="text" class="smlbox2" name="part_desc[]"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>

    <td><input type="text" name="part_note[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="part_internal_note[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="pc_rfq_date[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pc_rfq_cus_no[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pc_rfq_price[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="pc_po_date[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pc_po_cus_no[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pc_po_price[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="pv_po_date[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pv_po_cus_no[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pv_po_price[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mu_per[]" onblur="calculate_quote_rate(this)"></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" onclick="what_i_do(this);"></i></td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```

```
</form>
```

And JQuery is:-

```
  <script>
function what_i_do(that) {
    initid++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('what_i_do');
    var divtest = document.createElement("tr");
    divtest.setAttribute("class", "removeclass" + initid);
    divtest.setAttribute("id", "removeclass" + initid);
    var rdiv = 'removeclass' + initid;
    divtest.innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" name="item_no[]"></td><td colspan="3"> <table> <tr> <td><input type="text" class="smlbox" name="part_no[]" onblur="checkavailpart(this)"></td><td><input type="number" class="smlbox" name="qty[]"></td><td> <input type="number" class="smlbox price_quotd_cls" name="price_quotd[]"> </td></tr><tr> <td colspan="3"><input type="text" class="smlbox2" name="part_desc[]"></td></tr></table> </td><td><input type="text" name="part_note[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="part_internal_note[]"></td><td><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="pc_rfq_date[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="pc_rfq_cus_no[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="pc_rfq_price[]"></td><td><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="pc_po_date[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="pc_po_cus_no[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="pc_po_price[]"></td><td><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="pv_po_date[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="pv_po_cus_no[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="pv_po_price[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="mu_per[]" onblur="calculate_quote_rate(this)"></td><td><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x" style="color:red" onclick="remove_education_fields(' + initid + ');"></i></td>';
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);

}
</script>
```

When I am submitting the form I use to get only zero index data. I have tried to clone the table row but there also I am not getting the value of the form which have been appended by the JQuery.
Please Help me out of this Problem
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in your appended html :

```
 divtest.innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" name="item_no[]"></td><td colspan="3"> <table> <tr> <td>.....
```

remove all spaces between tags

Comment: try replacing
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
with 
    $('#what_i_do').append(divtest.innerHTML);

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your submit `button` is inside `form` tag, 
then you can just append your html code inside `tbody` tag : 
**#what_i_do** refer to `tbody` tag

```
$("#what_i_do tr").append('<tr class="removeclass'+id+'" id="removeclass'+id+'">'+ 'html code'+ '</tr>');
```

Comment: you're welcome, i'm happy for being helpful. if you can accept this answer, so other people can use it. Thanks